# How can I share an Entity for other entities' OneToMany

Tags: jpa

I have an Entity look like this.

```
@Entity
class Property extends BaseEntity {
    @Basic
    private String name;
    @Basic
    private String value;
}
```

The basic intention is using this Entity as other Entities properties.

```
@Entity
class MyEntity extends BaseEntity {
    @OneToMany
    private List<Property> properties;
}

@Entity
class YourEntity extends BaseEntity {
    @OneToMany
    private List<Property> properties;
}
```

How can I do this? Do I have to define each owner's field in `Property`?

```
@Entity
class Property extends BaseEntity {
    @Basic
    private String name;
    @Basic
    private String value;
    @ManyToOne(optional = true)
    private MyEntity myEntity;
    @ManyToOne(optional = true)
    private YourEntity yourEntity;
    @ManyToOne(optional = true)
    private OtherEntity otherEntity;
}
```

Comment: There are many ways to do it, it all depends on your 'property' and what level of sharing you want to have between other entities.  Can for instance, YourEntity, MyEntity and others all reference the exact same property?  Or will a poperty be unique per referencing entity.  If it is the later, you might want to look into aggregate collections, so that each owning entity gets its own Property table for its references, and the Property doesn't need a unique ID.  If it is to be shared, it needs its own ID that identifies it, or you can make the name/value pair the composite id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it is a good solution You represented here. There is the option to create a join table which will help you to keep the entity "cleaner" (and also could be used as a [ManyToMany](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany). In most of the cases I prefer to use the option You provided [simplicity is a gooooood thing :) ], but other colleagues got different view on this problem.

**TL.DR:** Your provided code is working and I personally prefer it. There are other ways but those are a bit slower etc.